# Deserialize a string containing special characters

Tags: .net, json-deserialization

I have a string that comes in containing, but not limited to "Æ", however, when I deserialize this into an object, it turns the character into a "?". Is there a way to deserialize this, and retain the "Æ" as the string?

Comment: Json.net should correctly handle all strings provided they are *correct* strings. Could the problem be with the way you *get* the string? For instance, if you do `File.ReadAllText` to get it, which encoding are you specifying? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: My point is that most likely the character has already been mangled, before you try to using Json.net to deserialize json.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Encoding.UTF8`. 
I tested it in my example as below:

```
var a = new Person("Ællo", 33);
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(output));
fs.Close();
```

You can see the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount`. It encodes string to bytes.
And This is the Deserialization example as below:

```
byte[] buffer;
fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
Person readPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
```

You can see the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`.
It works well.